# Prevent Outlook iPhone app from automatically deleting meeting emails

Tags: email, ms-office, ios

I'm using Outlook on my iPhone to read my email. When I receive a meeting notice and acknowledge it, Outlook adds it to my calendar then deletes the email. Is there a way to disable Outlook automatically deleting the meeting email?

Comment: Perhaps there's an option to prevent automatically accepting meeting invites?

Comment: Actually no. It is not so much deleting the email as it is moving it to the calendar. Outlook has had that behavior for as long as I can remember. And I am not aware of any way to change that behavior.